# Create Android Local Calendar without sync

Tags: java, android, calendar, google-calendar-api

I've been fighting for so long with this calendar stuff. I want to create a LOCAL Calendar which does NOT sync with any account.

I've created a local calendar with the following code:

```
public static long createLocalCalendar()
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(
                Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, 
        "nav_shift_manager"); //Account name becomes equal to "nav_shift_manager" !!TEST!!
        values.put(
                Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, 
                CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL);
        values.put(
                Calendars.NAME, 
        "NAV Shift Manager Calendar");
        values.put(
                Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, 
        "NAV Shift Manager Calendar");
        values.put(
                Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR, 
                0xffff0000);
        values.put(
                Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL, 
                Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_OWNER);
        values.put(
                Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT, 
        "some.account@googlemail.com");
        values.put(
                Calendars.CALENDAR_TIME_ZONE, 
        "Europe/London");
        Uri.Builder builder = 
            CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon(); 
        builder.appendQueryParameter(
                Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, 
        "com.navshiftmanager");
        builder.appendQueryParameter(
                Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, 
                CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL);
        builder.appendQueryParameter(
                CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, 
        "true");
        Uri uri = TrocasNAVApp.getContext().getContentResolver().insert(builder.build(), values);

        // Now get the CalendarID :
        return Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
    }
```

I ran this app on my Sony XPERIA J and it works perfectly! However I've tried it on a Samsung Galaxy S3 and it simply doesn't work.

First of all, each event that is created, the device is automatically setting the event as "dirty" and "deleted". I don't get it at all. It seems that he is expecting some kind of syncronization with something, but i have explicetly written that I want an ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL. I trully don't understand why the same code in different phones work differently. On my XPERIA J, added events work perfectly, if I delete them, they just disapear forever.

On my Samsung S3, all events are set to "deleted" and "dirty" automatically, I click to delete them and they never get deleted as they seem to be expecting some kind of sync. It means that the trick to check "deleted" cannot be used, since they are ALWAYS set to "deleted".

Shouldn't the behaviour of android calendars be universal?

Comment: This has happened after updating my Android version from 4.1.2 to 4.3. Any clue?

Comment: have you been able to resolve this issue?